# Little space between ul border and li background

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem, there is a little problem on my menu, there is a little space between the ul border and the li background, here's my code:

Menu code:

```css
.menu_base {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 75%;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-top: 0px solid;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-color: #ff6eff;
}

.button {
  float: left;
}

.button a {
  padding: 15px 15px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ff6eff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.button a:hover {
  background-color: #ff6eff;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu_base">
  <li class="button"><a href="/index.php" class="<?php if($filename == 'index.php') { echo 'active'; } ?>">Accueil</a></li>
  <li class="button" style="float: right"><a href="/clients/signup.php" class="<?php if($filename == 'signup.php') { echo 'active'; } ?>">Inscription</a></li>
  <li class="button" style="float: right"><a href="/clients/connexion.php" class="<?php if($filename == 'connexion.php') { echo 'active'; } ?>">Connexion</a></li>
</ul>
```

Excepted result: (From Firefox)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e62BM.png

Actual result: (From Chrome)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3wYU.png

Comment: Sounds like a chrome bug to me. Try updating chrome, but do keep in mind the version of chrome you are currently using, look if the same thing happens on other chromium browsers. If the same thing still happens in the newest version of chrome, consider reporting a bug.

Comment: Maybe... I tried to update my browser, but no changes. I will report this bug, thanks for your reply !

Comment: Looks like a border issue, set border at button to 0 or add, play with it.

Comment: when i set border 1px in menu, issue is gone

Comment: Yes that's true... Really weird, I will let the border stay at this size so...

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the normalize CSS to the top op your CSS file?

All browsers sort of add their own style which can cause problems when adding CSS to your site. By normalizing the CSS you get the same margin, padding etc for all browsers. You can use Eric Meyers normalize CSS. Just copy the CSS from the link below and add it to the top of your CSS file.

You can find it here: https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/